# I am trying to run a javascript function off a return keystroke however my syntax is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, syntax

I am having in issue executing my javascript I am  very new to javascript / jquery and may have bad syntax. My IE8  browser does not like my code and says  "The value of the property 'returnScript' is null or undefined not a function object where have I gone awry ?

```
<input id="keyword_box_sub" class="ac_input" type="text" value="" onfocus="if is.value == 'Search for products' ||this.value == 'Enter keyword or item #' ) {this.value = ''; $('#keyword_box_sub').removeClass('ac_input error').addClass('ac_input');}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search for products'; }" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="returnScript(event);">



$(keyword_box_sub).onkeypress=function returnScript(event);

function returnScript(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        getSearchSubString(); 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: <input id="keyword_box_sub" class="ac_input" type="text" value="" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search for products' ||this.value == 'Enter keyword or item #' ) {this.value = ''; $('#keyword_box_sub').removeClass('ac_input error').addClass('ac_input');}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search for products'; }" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="returnScript(event);"> here is my call

Comment: remove `function` and `event` in the first line

Comment: Just edit your question and add the code which is there in comments to help others also!

Comment: @Joren it won't be enough.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
$(keyword_box_sub)[0].onkeypress = returnScript;
```

Or:

```
$(keyword_box_sub)[0].onkeypress = function(e) {
    returnScript(e);
});
```

Or

```
$(keyword_box_sub).keypress(returnScript);
```

Or

```
$(keyword_box_sub).keypress(function(e) {
    returnScript(e);
});
```

Essentially, adding `()` invokes the function immediately. So when you want the function as a parameter, remove those `()` and just reference the func name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those first two examples will break won't they? Shouldn't it be `$(selector)[0].onkeypress = function(){}`?

Comment: Yes yes yes, forgot that I need to reference the `0` object, and thanks @kapep -- edited.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Your syntax should be this:

```
$(keyword_box_sub).on('keypress', function (event) {
  returnScript(event);
});
```

Comment: so remove my onkeypress attribute from the id of the input box? as well

Comment: Yes. It's always better to specify your event handling with JavaScript rather than inside html attributes for both organization and efficiency. What you really _should_ do is move all of those event attributes into jQuery event handlers.

Comment: I removed it however it didnt work still im using IE8 , does it mattter there is a seperate div on the page with the sae id in a seperate class? or no it means all the Keyword_box_sub will run the function anytime the event is trigger correct?

Comment: Yes that could very well be the problem. All ID's on the page should be unique. No two elements should ever have the same ID.